# Opencart showing error when changed the url

Tags: php, security, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using `opencart 2.0.2.0`. I was just checking some random tricks and i write the url `index.php?route=common/home` to `index.php?route=common/home%00`. And it showed me an error `Warning: is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in \system\engine\action.php  on line 18` Didn't understand why this happened. Any one can please help me to know why this error occured and how can i solve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that it's actually a bug in PHP (reported [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69353) @ 2/4/2015 and already fixed)

**What's your problem about?**

Null byte `(%00)` causes truncation in PHP strings (which is normal I think because PHP strings are implemented through c strings)

**So what's happening in OC?**

- Open the file `<OC_ROOT>\system\engine\action.php` (the one you got the error in), class `Action` resides there and it's responsible for parsing the route parameter, determining the appropriate controller to be loaded + which function in that controller to call and keeping the method arguments so as to be passed later during execution
- In that line
  `$file = DIR_APPLICATION . 'controller/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\', '..'), '', $path) . '.php';`
  You will notice that the controller file is loaded through appending a `.php` to the `$path` variable constructed by parsing the route parameter, since you have added an extra null byte to the route, `$file` looks like this: `bla bla bla/common/home\0.php`, the `\0` results in stripping the `.php`which leads to a non existing file path, that's why OC loads the error page

**How to solve it**
Simply turn off warnings from your project, If you mean by "how can i solve it?" making it work, then just strip null bytes from route parameter before parsing it (in the same file), but I don't advise you to do that because it's a handled hack and you will be de-handling it :D

Answer (score 0):

This is only warning for this opencart version. For quick solution, You will add "error_reporting(0);" in the __construct function.

Thank You.